# How to make setup file(.exe) from netbeans. And don't need to open xamp for database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Hope you guyes very fine! Well, i like to create application with netbeans using java code. I can make simple application with mysql database. Though after "built and run" if we run the jar file it’s need to stay run mysql server from xammp or any for for database. if i'm going to run it to another computer the computer must have installed the jdk and keep run the mysql server.

My questions are:

1. how can i run netbeans application with database without using xammp application.
2. how can i make setupable application like .exe file.

Thanks regard!

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use a different database such as SQL server also you can use MYSQL workbench and connect the database using JDBC.
2. [Here is the answer](https://youtu.be/2QNGdKdWSyM) just click and watch it!!!!